# Inconsistent values for created_tmp_tables server status variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I log into the (RDS) mysql server with the console client in two terminals, use the same database (not that that should matter), and run the query `show status like 'created%'` in each. They show a consistent number - no matter how many times I make the query, the answer doesn't change.

But they disagree with each other. Moreover,any time I `use` a different database, that query gives a different response, though that variable is supposed to be for the whole server.

The MySQL page gives this explanation for the variable:

> The number of internal temporary tables created by the server while executing statements.
>
> You can compare the number of internal on-disk temporary tables created to the total number of internal temporary tables created by comparing the values of the Created_tmp_disk_tables and Created_tmp_tables variables.

Can anybody explain why this would be happening? I can't understand how that variable could decrease *at all*, but the two sessions giving different numbers has me extra-stumped.

Comment: And you're certain the console client also goes to the same SERVER ?

Comment: Completely. It's an rds instance, and if I run a slow query on one console, `show processlist` displays it on the other.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html you can request this specific status information both per session as well as globally.

Can you give us the output of

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE ...
```

and

```
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE ...
```

Comment: When I'm next at the office I can.. but one of those variables is only available in the global scope: `Created_tmp_files numeric GLOBAL`